# How to have the same size for all item of a gridView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a `gridview`, for each item i have an `imageview` with 3 `textView`s, my problem that i am using `wrap_ content` for the size of item so I haven't the same size for all items. My `gridview` code is given below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/back_ground">
    <GridView

            android:id="@+id/gridView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2.0"
            android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
            android:columnWidth="@dimen/grid_column"

            style="@style/grid_space"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:persistentDrawingCache="animation|scrolling"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:stackFromBottom="false"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="48dp">
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout
```

the code of my item :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="@drawable/round_boutton"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
            android:text="TextView"

            android:id="@+id/textView1"

            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/orangemil"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textSize="14dip"


            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"></TextView>

    <TextView android:text="  "
              android:id="@+id/textView2"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="@color/white"></TextView>

    <TextView android:text="   "
              android:id="@+id/textView3"
              android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="@color/white"></TextView>
    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to use a fixed size:

```
gridView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150,150)); //dimension in px
```

Comment: Set a fixed height on the RelativeLayout item.

Comment: you have to add image view in gridview?

Answer (score 1):

if you have to add imageview? then
make Dynamic imageview like this

```
public class DynamicImageView extends ImageView {

    public DynamicImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final Drawable d = this.getDrawable();

        if (d != null) {
            // ceil not round - avoid thin vertical gaps along the left/right edges
        final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = (int) Math.ceil(width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth());
            this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

and implement it like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <this.is.packagename.DynamicImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textColor="@color/black" 
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

By this you will get same size of imageview how ever how many column you specify

```
  <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:numColumns="3" >
        </GridView>
```

if you getting any implementing problem then ask to me

Comment: my Problem isn't with image, because all the image have the some size. but with the textView I am using wrap content for the size. I would like that the height of my row is given by the big item.

Answer (score 0):

put your textview inside the linerlayout like this, it may solve your problem

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TextView1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="14dip" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView2" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView3" >
    </TextView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</LinearLayout>
```